# Android - Add image dynamically to existing list view row

Tags: android-layout, dynamic, android-listview

[Link to the image which depicts the expected requirement](http://www.4shared.com/photo/GBMU93Yf/adv_prj_image.html)

I am trying to achieve the above in a list view. The first list row is initial state and it gets updated based on available data in local sqlite DB. There are two ImageView as shown below in the layout and also correspondingly reflected in the above illustration namely a image left to the Title and one above it.The updates are basically images and color codes tied to that title. Please provide guidelines to insert the image view [one at top of the title] dynamically to the list row when that particular list row item gets updated with color code.

below is the layout and need to add the dynamic image after "list_image4" in the actual view

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/rlLocList"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dip">

                <!--  ListRow Left side Thumbnail image -->
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:id="@+id/thumbnail3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dip"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1dip">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/list_image3"
                        android:layout_width="50dip"
                        android:layout_height="50dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/content_picture">
                    </ImageView>

                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- Right end Arrow -->
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/title2"
                    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/navigation_next_item">
                </ImageView>

                <!--  ListRow top side Thumbnail image to show color code -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lLLocListLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="10dip"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/title2"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/title2">

                <ImageView
                     android:id="@+id/list_image4"
                     android:layout_width="15dip"
                     android:layout_height="10dip"
                     android:background="#ffff">
                </ImageView>
                </LinearLayout>

                <!-- Title -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbnail3"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail3"
                    android:text="Item-1"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#ffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold">
                </TextView>
            </RelativeLayout>
```